# Move a ToolStripMenuItem to nest inside another

Tags: vb.net, menustrip

I have googled away under my head wants to explode under various search strings and cannot find answer.
I have a tool strip arranged as such:

[image: MenuStrip]

I want to move the items "PDF Merge" and "Single Page PDF Merge" to be under the sub menu "PDF Tools"

I cannot for the life of me workout how to do it. Clicking and dragging allows me to reorder the menu items but not move them to the new sub menu. I try dragging and hovering over the little arrow that appears on the "PDF Tools" item but that doesn't do anything.

There has to be a easy way to do this in the designer but can't find anything in the menu properties that looks like "Parent" or "Owner" that I can change.

Any Help?

Comment: Cut, select subitem, Paste.

Comment: @HansPassant, just be aware that doing that will remove the `Handles` clause from any event handlers for that menu item. You can reselect any orphaned event handlers in the _Properties_ window after pasting, or just readd the `Handles` clause(s) manually.

Comment: The other option is to edit the designer code file by hand. It's generally to be avoided but is necessary/desirable in certain cases. Just be sure to take a backup before doing it.